# Rich Text IDE

Tags: html, css, ide, fckeditor

Does anyone know of a javascript based Rich Text box that behaves a bit like an IDE so that in a management system I can provide a text area for CSS and/or one for HTML to be written into the box and the input is colour coded like it is if you edit in Notepad++, Visual Studio etc Customsiation of the colours would be superb but certainly not essential!

I was sure there must be at least one but I'm struggling to find any through Google searches and instead am getting numerous results for FCKEditor style Rich Text Boxes.

Thanks for any help!

Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/) loks like what you want.

I was also going to suggest [Bespin](http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/bespin/) but I think browser technology needs to catch up with it (it uses HTML 5 etc.)

Comment: CodeMirror is exactly what I was after, that's superb thanks Brian.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you need. What I understood is that you are looking for a tool, where you input HTML in one textbox, CSS in another one, and the tool applies the style to the HTML to color the HTML like in Notepad++.

If this is the case, I don't know what you expect as an end result. Is it inline styling, so that you can paste the result on a page and have it displayed? To me all this sounds like it would make things more complicated than you would do it by hand - maintainability, etc. I don't think you'll find such a tool anywhere, it doesn't seem logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question but you should have a look at 
[syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/)

Answer (score 0):

I've also been sent this from another source for another option called 'CodePress': [CodePress link on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codepress)

This one includes line numbers and different language options, might be useful to someone as I think, by the looks of it, I prefer this option to CodeMirror.

Comment: I tinkered with CodePress, and it looked nice, but since it converted the textareas in my form to iframes, they weren't being submitted. I tried to find documentation on how to fix this, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: Is CodePress a dead project now?